# Android intermittent SSL Socket read timed out

Tags: java, android, ssl, android-async-http

I am building an android app that makes calls to an HTTP/REST api. 
I have self signed a certificate for testing and added it to my phones trust store.

I have run into a very strange issue where I will receive the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:705)
...
```

I am at a total loss as to how or why this is happening.
Important notes:

- This happens randomly, comes back after lots of request but sometimes goes away for a day or two.
- I cannot reliably reproduce the issue.
- I have adjusted the timeout settings with no results.
- The issue outlives the life-cycle of the application. Restarting the app has no effect, although it seems to resolve itself within 5 mins.
- If I am using a cookie store, removing it seems to resolve the issue temporally. If I am not using a cookie store, a new instance of the HttpClient needs to be created (as cookies persist temporally with the instance of the HttpClient)
- It is not a DNS issue as I can resolve the endpoint (as I have another app that uses the same endpoint and the same crt).
- I am using the AsyncHttp library for android, but the issue still happens outside of using that library.
- I have tried another device with another version of android (no luck).

Interesting things I have tried:

- I created a new AsyncHttp instance, made a request (without setting the cookiestore) and successfully received a response. Then the app creates another AsyncHttp instance with the cookie store and the issue persists. Even outside the app life-cycle, the first (non cookied) request will work, but the second will not.
- I tired turning off tcp_timestamp (temporally via the file in proc). No change.

If anyone has some idea or experience with a similar issue, please let me know.

Comment: "a new instance of the HttpClient needs to be created" -- unless you are using Apache's independent packaging of HttpClient, I suggest that you use some other HTTP API (e.g., `HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp). Android deprecated HttpClient in Android 5.1, removed it from the SDK in Android 6.0, and has been advising developers to stop using it for a few years now. Beyond that, are you seeing anything in the server logs of note?

Comment: Ill look into HttpURLConnection. I am using cz.msebera.android.httpclient.  Nothing in the server logs. It never reaches the server and the headers come back null when the error is thrown.

Comment: You adjusted the timeout settings to what?

Comment: I tried: short (10 seconds), long (1+ mins), default (not setting it at all)

Comment: @CommonsWare I ripped out all instances of httpClient and moved to OkHttp. The issue persists.

Comment: OK. What evidence do you have that the problem is on the client side, versus the server?

Comment: I am able to connect to the same endpoints/API calls from the phone, while the app is throwing the exception via the web browser on the phone. The same exact API being used is shared with a chrome extension that has yet to reproduce the same issue. There is no log data of the request making it to the server. (Apache access and error turn up nothing). If it is possibly somewhere else in the network stack (not apache), could you suggest a log to monitor?

Comment: Scratch everything I just said. I installed tcpdump on my server and monitored the 443 traffic until the bug came up. I then triggered a request and saw that the server received the request (or at least some of it) but never responded. So this is potentially pointing at a server issue.

Comment: Hard to see what *else* could possibly cause a read timeout, and specifically what kind of client-side or Android bug would cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a session related bug with my server code.

Comment: I am having exactly same kind of an issue, but the issue gets resolved as soon as I restart the android device. Can you please tell what exactly was your server side bug?

Comment: The issue I had was a session lock issue with PHP + Apache. The solution was to call `session_write_close` as soon as I read the data I needed from the session.